# Querying mongoid for objects with array containing specific values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I'm trying to retrieve only books where only authors in favorite_authors are among the authors for the book. (note: not an exact match, but an exclusion of all books with any authors other than those in favorite_authors).

```
favorite_authors = User.favorite_authors
=> [BSON::ObjectId('5363c73c4d61635257516000'),
BSON::ObjectId('5363c73c4d61635257516001'),
BSON::ObjectId('5363c73c4d61635257516002'),
BSON::ObjectId('5363c73c4d61635257516003'),
BSON::ObjectId('5363c73c4d61635257516004'),
BSON::ObjectId('5363c73c4d61635257516005'),
BSON::ObjectId('5363c73c4d61635257516006')]

class Author
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, type: String

class Book
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, type: String
  field :authors, type: Array
```

Some naive pseudo code to give you an idea of what I'd like to do:

```
Book.where(authors: relevant_authors).not.where(authors: !relevant_authors)
```

Ideally, I'd like to accomplish this using a Mongoid Origin query.